# Error in setting keyboard shorcut for extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, manifest

I am developing a chrome extension where i am setting a shortcut for some actions. But the problem is i am unable to set the shortcut(**Alt+Z+3**) using the manifest file

```
"commands": {
"fullScreen": {
  "suggested_key": {
    "default": "Alt+Z+3",
    "mac": "Alt+Z+3"
  },
  "description": "Test"
 },
 "_execute_browser_action": {
  "suggested_key": {
    "windows":"Alt+Z+3",
    "mac":"Alt+Z+3",
    "chromeos": "Alt+Z+3",
    "linux":"Alt+Z+3"
  }
 },
 "_execute_page_action": {
  "suggested_key": {
    "default": "Alt+Z+3",
    "windows": "Alt+Z+3",
    "mac": "Alt+Z+3"
  }
 }
 },
```

It is throwing errors like **`Invalid value for 'commands[1].mac': Alt+Z+3.`**

But when i change the shortcut to (**Alt+Shift+3**)

```
  "commands": {
"fullScreen": {
  "suggested_key": {
    "default": "Alt+Shift+3",
    "mac": "Alt+Shift+3"
  },
  "description": "Toggle feature foo"
},
"_execute_browser_action": {
  "suggested_key": {
    "windows":"Alt+Shift+3",
    "mac":"Alt+Shift+3",
    "chromeos": "Alt+Shift+3",
    "linux":"Alt+Shift+3"
  }
},
"_execute_page_action": {
  "suggested_key": {
    "default": "Alt+Shift+3",
    "windows": "Alt+Shift+3",
    "mac": "Alt+Shift+3"
  }
}
```

},

it is not throwing any error.  How to set the shortcut of Alt+Z+3 in the extension.

Comment: There's no such *modifier* key as `Z`. Use Ctrl, Alt, Shift. See the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use such combination. 

The scheme is the following:

```
(Alt | Ctrl) + [Shift] + <N>
```

Where:

1. Alt or Ctrl is required
2. Shift is optional
3. <N> – means a single key. 
   Allowed values:

   > *A-Z, 0-9, Comma, Period, Home, End, PageUp, PageDown, Space, Insert, Delete, Arrow keys, and the Media Keys.*

Also, you can test combinations using "configure commands" dialog:

```
chrome://extensions/configureCommands
```

Docs: [chrome.commands](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands)